# How to add all signers name in email body in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have to send Document to Signer1 and Signer2.In email template (In email body not in subject line) I need to add both signers name.If I use [[RecipientName]] includes only Signer1 name or Signer2 name not both.

How to achieve this with docusign..

Comment: Example:(Email body has to be like this)
                                                                                                               Hi (Signer1Name) and (Signer2Name),
--------
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the email body to say

> Hi Signer 1 and Signer 2, ...

You will need to explicitly set the "email blurb" for the envelope. Use the field `emailBlurb` in the [`envelopeDefinition` of Envelopes: create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definitions--envelopeDefinition)

You can set the email body for all recipients (as shown above), or you can set different email bodies for each individual recipient.

Comment: Could you please explain to me with example  how to add email body(message) and email subject line from json to docusign template                 Note : Json string has to be passed as http request.